# SQL query how to group separately same results wihin incremental keys RANK

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

I have A and B columns. I need to group Column A with following way: 2&3, 5&6, 8&9&10 together based on values in B column. Column A is always increment 1 thru 10. I have issues finding a way in SQL to group 5&6 and 8&9&10 separately since they have same B values (1.4). I want to group incremental A values together (5,6,8,9,10 is not incremental due to missing 7). Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
A   B
1   1.0   
2   1.1  
3   1.1  
4   1.3  
5   1.4  
6   1.4  
7   1.45  
8   1.4  
9   1.4  
10  1.4
```

Comment: please show the expected output.

Comment: A      B 
1      1.0
2-3   1.1
4      1.3
5-6   1.4
7      1.45
8-10 1.4

Answer (score 1):

This is a [gaps-and-islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) type question, because you do not want to just group by `B`, you only want to group by consecutive `B` relative to `A`.

rextester: http://rextester.com/UEE36579

```
select 
    minA = min(a)
  , maxA = max(a)
  , B
  , rnk = dense_rank() over (order by min(a))
from (select a, b
  , rn_a = row_number() over (order by a) 
  , rn_b = row_number() over (partition by b order by a) 
from t) as cte
group by B, rn_b - rn_a
order by minA, b
```

returns:

```
+------+------+------+-----+
| minA | maxA |  B   | rnk |
+------+------+------+-----+
|    1 |    1 | 1.00 |   1 |
|    2 |    3 | 1.10 |   2 |
|    4 |    4 | 1.30 |   3 |
|    5 |    6 | 1.40 |   4 |
|    7 |    7 | 1.45 |   5 |
|    8 |   10 | 1.40 |   6 |
+------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: @antbithia Added `maxA`

Answer (score 0):

Dump into a temp table with an indicator of the groupings...

```html
INSERT INTO #TempTable(ColA, ColB, GroupCol)
SELECT A, 
       B,
       CASE 
           WHEN A = 1 THEN 1
           WHEN A = 2 OR A = 3 THEN 2
           WHEN A = 4 THEN 4
           WHEN A = 5 or A = 6 THEN 5
           WHEN A = 7 THEN 6
           WHEN A = 8 OR A= 9 or A = 10 THEN 7
           ELSE NULL
       END AS GroupCol
FROM OrginalTable
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>ColA</th>
  <th>ColB</th>
  <th>GroupCol</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1.0</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1.1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>1.1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1.3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>1.4</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>1.4</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>1.45</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>1.4</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>1.4</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1.4</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The you can use a "group by" using the groupCol

Comment: Your solution assumes we know the values beforehand. However, this should be coded to work for any dataset.  Thanks